# Jenkins build for Python code using Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I do not know how to configure a Jenkins pipeline that would build Python Project (e.g. every time a pull request is approved) - how do I configure that?

P.S. I looked at Jenkins docs, but it's mainly for Java. I want to do it for a Python project using Jenkins pipeline (Jenkinsfile) and I just need to checkout code and do some sonar scan.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Although jenkins offers a lot of support for java development, it's important to know that you can always use sh commands (or windows cmd if it's the case) to do whatever you want.

About your question:

- (Everytime a pull request is approved), easy one, the answer is to set-up a webhook trigger, you can find them on your github's repository settings (if your role gives you access), you should look for github plugins that let's you do this task but usually providing access credentials both for jenkins and github on each other and choosing the trigger you want will do the job. (Pull request trigger is an option of course)
- Jenkinsfile as I said can execute sh commands inside your agent so you can just do whatever you need to about python, here you have some little example:

```
 stage('SetUpPythonProject') {

            steps {
                echo 'Moving to specific folder'
                sh '''
                cd /home/my_user/project_folder
                '''
                echo 'Executing python project'
                sh '''
                git clone http://credentials@git-repo.git
                git checkout my_branch
                python3 git-repo/my_script.py
                '''
            }
        }
```